# Java Spring - How to fix HttpMessageNotWritableException Infinite Recursion JSON response?

Tags: java, json, spring, http, spring-boot

So I have a simple method in java spring that returns a class as a ResponseBody:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "update", method = RequestMethod.PUT)
public @ResponseBody JKResponse update() {
    return new JKResponse();
}
```

And the JKResponse class is as follows:

```
@JsonAutoDetect(fieldVisibility = JsonAutoDetect.Visibility.ANY, 
                isGetterVisibility = JsonAutoDetect.Visibility.ANY,
                getterVisibility = JsonAutoDetect.Visibility.ANY)
public class JKResponse implements Serializable {
    static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    @JsonProperty
    private List<String> stuff;

    public JKResponse() {
        this.stuff = new ArrayList<String>();
    }

    public void setStuff(final List<String> stuff) {
        this.stuff = stuff;
    }

    public List<String> getStuff() {
        return this.stuff;
    }

    /*
       THIS METHOD IS CAUSING THE INFINITE RECURSION, BUT WHY?
    */
    public ResponseEntity<JResponse> getResponseEntity() {
        return new ResponseEntity<JResponse>(this, HttpStatus.OK);
    }
}
```

But when I use postman to called the "update" API route, I get the following error:

```
Failed to write HTTP message: org.springframework.http.converter.HttpMessageNotWritableException: Could not write content: Infinite recursion (StackOverflowError) (through reference chain: org.springframework.http.ResponseEntity["body"]->com.proj.services.JKService["responseEntity"]->org.springframework.http.ResponseEntity["body"] and so on...
```

And the JSON displayed in postman is:

```
{"responseEntity":{"headers":{},"body":{"responseEntity":{"headers":{},"body":{"responseEntity":{"headers":{},"body":{"responseEntity":{"headers":{},"body":{"responseEntity":{"headers":{},"body":{"responseEntity":{"headers":{},"body":{"responseEntity":{"headers":{},"body":{"responseEntity":{"headers":{},"body":{"responseEntity":{"headers":{},"body":{"responseEntity":{"headers":{},"body":{"responseEntity":{"headers":{},"body":{"responseEntity":{"headers":{},"body":{"responseEntity":{"headers":{},"body":{"responseEntity":{"headers":{},"body":{"responseEntity":{"headers":{},"body": and so on...
```

And I can't figure out what is causing this, and why this is happening. Any advice?

Comment: You probably need to give us more information. I tried you're code and it works for me.

Comment: Oh I actually figured out WHY it was happening (I edited the class above and added a getResponseEntity method back, which was the problem)...For some reason returning new ResponseEntity<>(this, HttpStatus.OK), causes an infinite recursion. How come this happens?

Comment: Because it tries to serialize the entity recursively. To serialize object it has to get all attributes from it, then all attributes from it's attributes, then all attributes from it's attributes' attributes and so on. And because one of attributes is entity itself, this will never end.

Comment: is there any other way to do the thing I want to do then?

Comment: I don't know what you want to do :-)

Comment: Basically return a response entity that wraps around the current object

Comment: try removing getterVisibility = JsonAutoDetect.Visibility.ANY from the annotation.

Comment: Didn't do anything unfortunately ;(

Comment: Aren't you trying to send the `responseEntity` to the user? Why do you need it? ResponseEntity is a Spring API data object, you don't need to send it to the user. Create one inside your controller's `update` method and just return it from there, user will get the object, the status code and other header from the entity.

Answer (score 0):

You don't usually need to send ResponseEntity to the user, ResponseEntity is the data object you use to tell Spring what it should return to the user. It is supposed to be used like this:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "update", method = RequestMethod.PUT)
public ResponseEntity<JKResponse> update () {
    HttpHeaders responseHeaders = new HttpHeaders();
    responseHeaders.set("Boiling", "True");
    return new ResponseEntity<JKResponse>(
            new JKResponse(), responseHeaders, HttpStatus.I_AM_A_TEAPOT);
}
```

And the user will get this:

```
$ curl -X PUT -i 127.0.0.1:8080/update
HTTP/1.1 418 
Server: Apache-Coyote/1.1
Boiling: True
Content-Type: application/json;charset=UTF-8
Transfer-Encoding: chunked
Date: Tue, 29 Dec 2015 20:03:51 GMT

{"stuff":[]}
```